# vue.js computed beginner

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to learn vue.js despite not having any background with javascript. I ran into some code when following a video that was teaching about 'computed', and I tried experimenting on it and had a bit of trouble along the way.

```
<div id='app'>
<p>Do you see me?</p>
<p v-if="show">Do you also see me?</p>
<button @click="showToggle1">Switch!</button>
</div>

new Vue({
el:'#app',
  data:{
  show = true;
  },

  computed:{
     showToggle1:function(){
     return this.show = !this.show
     }
  },

  methods:{
     showToggle2:function(){
     this.show = !this.show;
  }
});
```

Basically it's making "Do you also see me?" disappear and appear depending on the value of "show". I know that if you write @click:'showToggle2()' instead of @click:'showToggle1' at the button, the value changes and it works. I'm just having some trouble understanding how computed works and why showToggle1 doesn't change the value of show when I click the button

Comment: See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
Their documentation is very appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems.

First, you have syntactical problems. `data` is an object, so instead of:

```
data:{
  show = true;
}
```

Should be:

```
data:{
  show: true
}
```

Next, **computed properties** are to be used like... properties. For example, like declared in `data`. So, typicall, you read from them. You **don't execute computed properties** in `@click` events. So this code:

```
<button @click="showToggle1">Switch!</button>
```

Is not correct. It will error because `showToggle1` is not a method, it is, as said, a computed property. What you should have in `click` is a method, like:

```
<button @click="showToggle2">Switch!</button>
```

This will work because `showToggle2` is a method. And **you should use methods to perform changes**.

Not, before going into the last and most tricky part, here's a working demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    show: true
  },
  computed: {
    /*showToggle1: function() {
      return this.show = !this.show;
    }*/
  },
  methods: {
    showToggle2: function() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>


<div id='app'>
  <p>Do you see me?</p>
  <p v-if="show">Do you also see me?</p>
  <hr>
  Value of show: {{ show }}<br>
  <button @click="showToggle2">Switch2!</button>
</div>
```

The tricky part is your computed property (which I commented out in the code above):

```
  computed:{
     showToggle1:function(){
     return this.show = !this.show
     }
  },
```

Basically what it is doing is it is **automatically negating the value of `show` whenever it changes**.

This happens because the computed property is calculated whenever `show` updates. And what is happening is:

- You initialize `data` with `true` (because of `data: {show: true}`).
- The `showToggle1` computed auto-recalculates, because it has `this.show` inside of it (it depends on it).
- When recalculating, `showToggle1` sets the value of `show` to false (because of `return this.show = !this.show`).

That's why `show` becomes false.

And that's also why whenever you change (even from the method, which is the correct place) the value of `show` to `true` it will automatically go back to `false`. Because any change in `show` triggers the `showToggle1` computed recalculation, which sets `show` back to `false`.

In summary:

- Use methods to perform changes.
- Don't change properties inside computed properties.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a little trouble understanding the docs, but your explanation is easy to understand. :)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped!

Comment: My bad, i am still new with stackoverflow and thank you for the tips :)